# How to check the conformal prefactor in a correlation function?

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, correlation-functions, scale-invariance

In CFT it is usual practice to extract the so-called conformal prefactor from the correlators in order to isolate a function which depends only on the cross-ratios. For example the $4$-point function of identical scalar operators reads:

$$\langle \mathcal{O}_\Delta (x_1) \mathcal{O}_\Delta (x_2) \mathcal{O}_\Delta (x_3) \mathcal{O}_\Delta (x_4) \rangle = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{x_{12}^\Delta x_{34}^\Delta}} F(u,v)\,, \tag{1}$$

with $u,v$ the two independent cross-ratios. It seems to me that there is some arbitrariness in choosing the form of the prefactor: I could have also chosen $x_{13}^\Delta x_{24}^\Delta$ if I am not mistaken. But some prefactors do not guarantee that $F$ depends only on $u$ and $v$, for example if I just put $1$ instead of $x_{12}^\Delta x_{34}^\Delta$ then $F$ depends on more than $u$ and $v$. Also something like $x_{12}^{3\Delta} x_{13}^{\sqrt{\log\Delta}}$ is surely faulty as well.

My question is the following: **is there a simple test, such as a differential equation, that can be applied on the conformal prefactor to make sure it is a valid one?** I am looking at higher-point correlators (5-point at the moment), and for my purposes (more specifically for Mathematica manipulations) some prefactors are more convenient than others, that's why I am asking instead of just taking one of the standard ones.

Comment: Prefactor is a matter of taste, as long as it transforms in the same way under conformal transformations as the correlation function. The correlation function is conformally-covariant, not invariant. The role prefactor is to distill an invariant piece, which then can only depend on $u,v$.